# Excel formula help - exclude data if a checkbox is unchecked

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on a sheet to track my golf league scores and prize money. I came across an issue recently that I can't figure out. I have it set up to count the lowest score on a hole and assign a 'skin' to that player. Then it adds up the total prize money and divides by the number of skins won for this week. I added the check boxes to count how many players are in for skins this week, and am multiplying by the $3 buy-in to get the total prize money.

What i'm looking to do is exclude a player that is not checked for skins that week (if they are absent, etc.). I know I can just not put a score in their row, but if you are absent you still get a score (your average + 3), and this sheet is linked to the other sheets for overall points and standings and whatnot.

The formula I am using to show 'skin' is:

```
=IF((COUNTIF(E8:E28,MIN(E8:E28))=1),"Skin","")
```

And the formula to show the name is:

```
=IF(E31="Skin",INDEX($A$8:$A$28,MATCH(MIN(E8:E28),E8:E28,0)),"")
```

See the screen-grab for more clarity. You will see the two green boxes showing 'skin' and the players name, as well as the check boxes that I'd like to use to exclude data. for example in E7, if the 'skins' box was not checked, I would like that blue shaded "4" to not count, and a skin would be awarded to the last player in the column since he had the only other 4.

Any help would be appreciated!

[Golfleague1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQBgY.png)

Comment: I am confused.  The 2 players are eligible for a skin on hole 1 because they both have the lowest score.  If the other player with a score of 4 is eligible, then you are not going to have the ‘skins’ box unchecked and therefore the player you wish to allocate a skin to will be awarded it.

Comment: I see how this can be confusing, I didn't mention that we also are allowed to 'pre-play' if we know we will be absent ahead of time and use our scores from the previous week. in my example, if we said the 4 in E7 was from last weeks score, then the skins box would be unchecked. That player is absent and therefore not in the skins competition, but his 4 is interfering with the only other score of 4 that would actually be a skin.

Comment: Also, for the non-golfers, a skin can only be awarded if there is only one of the lowest score on a hole (eg. two 4's cancel each other out). This is why only two skins were awarded on holes 7 & 8. everything else cancelled out.

Comment: To me, you are unjustly adjusting the player’s score because it doesn’t fit with the criteria set where *”if you are absent you still get a score (your average +3)”*.  If the players average +3 = 4, the ‘skin’ check box will be checked.  If it is lower, he/she alone would have been awarded a skin (for the average score).  If it was higher, the ‘skin’ box would be unchecked, awarding the skin to the other player.

Comment: Well no, because if the player pre-played and we are using a score of 4 on the first hole, but they are absent this week then they are not entered in the skins game. the check boxes were originally just used to calculate how much prize money is available. If they are absent then they are not entered in the skins game.

Comment: In that case you could add a 'present' column.  If the player is absent, the sheet can then ignore the scores for that week and uncheck the 'skin' box.

Comment: I considered that, but it kind of brings me back to my original problem. I don't know the formula to exclude the data if the golfer is 'present' or not. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AdamV, reload Screen Shot & must include Row Numbers,,and in which Cells you have written both Formulas,, also data is Green Cell and painted with White so unable to justify the execution !!

Comment: @RajeshS I reloaded the image, and the formula =IF((COUNTIF(E8:E28,MIN(E8:E28))=1),"Skin","")
is in E31:M31.
The formula
=IF(E31="Skin",INDEX($A$8:$A$28,MATCH(MIN(E8:E28),E8:E28,0)),"") 
is in E32:M32. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I'm not a golfer.  Just curious what "skins" refers to (pelts of animals found on the golf course? Who is playing shirtless?).

Comment: @AdamV, check now I've posted the solution will help you to proceed.

Comment: @fixer1234 I guess it came from way back in the day when the prize money was carried around in a bag that was made from an animal skin. Who knows, all i care about is winning said skin haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This method will fix the issue:**

1. When Check Box is unchecked.

[image]

2. When Check Box is checked.

[image]

**How it Works:**

- After you draw *Check Boxes*, *Right Click* it & from Poped up Menu, hit *Format Control.*

[image]

- From *Control TAB* use *Cell Link* to link 
  Check Boxes as follows.
- First Check Box  Cell `H79`
- Second Check Box Cell `I79`
- Third Check Box  Cell `J79`

**Formula in Cell `H80`:**

```
 =IF(H$79=TRUE,IF(COUNTIF(H$58:H$77,MIN(H$58:H$77))=1,"Skin"," "),"")
```

**Formula in Cell `H81`:**

```
=IF(H$80="Skin",INDEX($G$58:$G$77,MATCH(MIN(H$58:H$77),H$58:H$77,0)),"")
```

*Fill both Formula Right.*

**N.B.**

- As your need apply same method to the required 
  Data Range, since I've used small potion only.
- Adjust Cell references as you need.
- You may hide Cells, Linked with Check boxes.

Comment: Thank you @RajeshS I will put that to use

Comment: @AdamV, glad to help you ,, keep asking ☺